# Get number of line of word number X in file

Tags: bash, unix

Need to make a shell script that splits every csv file that uses `\n` as separator, the limit per file is the number of words and 
I can't cut the line in half.

### Finished script with the help of a wizard!

Example:

```
sh SliceByWords.sh 1000 .
```

Slices every file by 1000 words and put every part into subfolder

---

```
        function has_number_number_of_words {
        re='^[0-9]+$'
        if ! [[ $1 =~ $re ]] ; then
            echo "error: Not a number, please run the command with the number of words per file" >&2; exit 1
        fi
    }
    #MAIN
    has_number_number_of_words $1
    declare -i WORDLIMIT=$1 # N of lines to part each file

    subdir="Result"
    mkdir $subdir
    format=*.csv
    for name in $format; do mv "$name" "${name// /___}"; done
    for i in $format;
    do
     if [[ "$i" == "$format" ]]
     then
        echo "No Files"
     else
        ( locali=$(echo $i | awk '{gsub(/ /,"\\ ");print}');
            localword=$i;
            FILENAMEWITHOUTEXTENSION="${localword%.*}" ;
            subnoext=$subdir"/"$FILENAMEWITHOUTEXTENSION;
            echo Processing file "$FILENAMEWITHOUTEXTENSION";
            awk  -v NOEXT=$subnoext -v wl=$WORDLIMIT  -F" " 'BEGIN{fn=1}{c+=NF}{sv=NOEXT"_snd_"fn".csv";print $0>sv;}c>wl{c=0;++fn;close(sv);}' $localword;

            )&


     fi
    done
    wait #wait
    for name in $format; do mv "$name" "${name//___/ }"; done
    echo All files done.
```

Since i couldnt figure out how to enter awk files with spaces , im using

```
   for name in $format; do mv "$name" "${name//___/ }"; done
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be a lot easier to handle with `awk`:

```
awk -F" " 'BEGIN{filenumber=1}{counter+=NF}{print $0 > FILENAME"_part_"filenumber} counter>1000{counter=0;++filenumber}' yourinputfile
```

`awk` here is:

1. Splitting each line by space `-F" "`
2. Before processing the file set the `filenumber` variable to 1
3. Bump the counter variable by the number of fields in the line `{counter+=NF}`
4. Print out the line to the file, numbered by a variable. Using the `FILENAME` built-in variable here to pull through `yourinputfile`. `{print $0 > FILENAME"_part_"filenumber}`
5. If the counter has popped over 1000, then send it back to 0 and bump the `filenumber` variable by 1 `counter>1000{counter=0;++filenumber}`

Minimized a bit:

```
awk -F" " 'BEGIN{fn=1}{c+=NF}{print $0>FILENAME"_part_"fn}c>1000{c=0;++fn}' yourinputfile
```

Comment: AMAZING! HOLY****! Are you some kind of wizard??? , seriously thanks, its waaaay beyond my understanding , but awesome will try to make it so it takes filename by $1 and wordlimit by $2, thank you so much . First i will learn it step by step , then steal the hell out of it haha

Comment: No worries. `awk` is pretty powerful stuff. For fun on your file just run `awk -F" " '{print $3}' yourfile.txt` You'll see that prints out the third word of each line. From there the rest is pretty easy to understand. And I'm definitely not a wizard. I'm not even that amazing at awk. There a few folks on here that are probably shaking their heads at some oddball way I went about solving this in awk and can rewrite this in like 30 characters. The mind boggles.

Comment: I just realized this misses the last little bit of the file. Need to add an END{} block. Updating incoming.

Comment: OK. Updated with that last END{} block.

Comment: Try `echo "Five spaces between a     b"` as input. Maybe not what OP wants.

Comment: Hi, back in the office , sory for the delay, the lights went out for 4 hours on friday. Getting an error with Filename_part_ . Tried exchanging it for "FILENAME_part_"

Comment: Also this awk cuts the line mid sentence. every 1000 words , it should cut after finishing the line. Thats why i need the line number for every 1000 words and not just cut it in the middle

Comment: Oh! Shoot. `awk` is still a good choice here. Just need to jostle this around a bit.

Comment: Made it work with 
        sv=FILENAME"_part_"int(counter/1000);
        print buffer > sv;
to go around the variable_string_int combo. Now trying to make it finish the line when buffering.

Comment: It actually makes it a lot easier since we don't have to bother with the for loop: `awk -F" " 'BEGIN{filenumber=1}{counter+=NF}{print $0 > FILENAME"_part_"filenumber} counter>1000{counter=0;++filenumber}' yourinputfile`

Comment: I've updated the answer doing it line by line instead of word by word.

Comment: PERFECT! , omg , haha , god i need to learn how to do this myself (new job , way out of my depth), now will just make some kind of sh that call this pararell for each file in the folder , and output every part to a subfolder and i finish my job . THANKS for your help @JNevill you're a saint

Comment: You can also send multiple files to awk by listing them behind the command. Tweaking how we bump/reset that `filenumber` variable you could probably just do it all there. That being said, I think it would be 100% reasonable to do the file looping in bash too. That would keep the `awk` command nice and small and easy to debug.

Comment: my friend need one last bit of help , the script works wonders , made it so it splices every csv in the folder to a subfolder . The only thing is that when the filename has a Space , awk says it cant open file . Updated original post with code